# How to get n number of entries from a namevaluecollection in batches

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using C#

So I have a namevaluecollection that can contain a variable number of entries generally 40-50.

What I want to do is take 3 entries at a time and process them, in order. For e.g. if entire collection = 9, then like take 1-3, then 4-6, then 7-9.

The problem is i am unable to get them recursively, also what happens if I have say 13 entries, then it would be like 3*4 + 1.

I tried to use .TAKE but don't know how to do this recursively.

Any pointers appreciated.

```
int TotalTestImage = TestImages.Count();
int y = 0;

int Interator = TotalTestImage / 3;

if((TotalTestImage % 3) != 0)
{
    Interator += 1;
}

int i = 0;

for(int k = 0; k < Interator; k++)
{
    sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\">");

    TestImages.Take(3).Skip(y * 3).ToList().ForEach( o => {
        switch (o.Key)
        {
            case "CaseID":
                CaseID = Convert.ToInt16(o.Value);
                break;
            default:
                i += 1;
                Controls = GetDropDown(o.Value);
                ActualValues.Add(o.Value);
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-md-3\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box box-success box-solid\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box-header with-border\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<h3 class=\"box-title\">Question {0}</h3>", i);
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box-tools pull-right\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<button type = \"button\" class=\"btn btn-box-tool\" data-widget=\"collapse\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<i class=\"fa fa-minus\"></i>");
                sb.AppendLine("</button>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box-body\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-9\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<img src =\"{0}\" alt=\"\" class=\"center-block\">", o.Key);
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-3\">");
                sb.AppendLine(Controls[1]);
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-top:10px\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-9\">");
                sb.AppendLine(Controls[0]);
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-3\"></div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                break;
        }
    });
    sb.AppendLine("</div>");
    y += 1;
}
```

Comment: Post your effort please, so we can have a base to start a productive discussion

Comment: You can do this sequentially using `.Take` and `.Skip`. But since you have not shown any code of what you have tried so far, there is not much help that can be provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this sequentially using `.Take` and `.Skip` in combination

```
var batchSize = 3;
var sequence = TestImages; //Uncertain what type is in TestImages
while(sequence.Any()) {
    sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\">");

    var batch = sequence.Take(batchSize);

    //process the batch
    processBatch(sb, batch);

    sb.AppendLine("</div>");

    sequence = sequence.Skip(batchSize);
}
```

The `processBatch` function would basically match what you were doing in the `ForEach`

```
void processBatch(StringBuilder sb, IEnumerabl<{TypeHere}> batch) {
    foreach(var o in batch) {
        switch (o.Key) {
            case "CaseID":
                CaseID = Convert.ToInt16(o.Value);
                break;
            default:
                i += 1;
                Controls = GetDropDown(o.Value);
                ActualValues.Add(o.Value);
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-md-3\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box box-success box-solid\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box-header with-border\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<h3 class=\"box-title\">Question {0}</h3>", i);
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box-tools pull-right\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<button type = \"button\" class=\"btn btn-box-tool\" data-widget=\"collapse\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<i class=\"fa fa-minus\"></i>");
                sb.AppendLine("</button>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"box-body\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-9\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<img src =\"{0}\" alt=\"\" class=\"center-block\">", o.Key);
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-3\">");
                sb.AppendLine(Controls[1]);
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-top:10px\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-9\">");
                sb.AppendLine(Controls[0]);
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-lg-3\"></div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Take() for the second item, you should skip the first items.

In your example,

```
var set1 = collection.Take(3);  // will get first 3 items
var set2 = collection.Skip(3).Take(3);  // will get first 4-6 items
.
.
.
```